# Automatically restart node server

Tags: node.js, restart, forever

How can I automatically restart my node js server every 4 hours automatically. There is a bug that only shows up after 4 hours and I want to be able to run it through the night.
I'm already using forever.
Thanks,
Arjun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't sound like you're really solving the problem... But you could use a crob job.

Something like:

`0 */4 * * * forever restart <MYSCRIPT.JS>`

Comment: Of course not. I just need to buy some time. This problem is way more complicated than I thought

Comment: Can you explain the syntax to me?

Comment: Of course, but it was presumptuous of me to assume you were on an OS that supports cron. Which OS are you running?