# Make Node Server Restart Proof

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, cron, forever

What I have now is a node server (with [**forever.js**](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) in [**Ubuntu 14.04 LTS**](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/)) which is needed to start each time server PC starts.

So, to do that what we need is this command (every time PC start or restarts)-

```
forever start /var/www/websocket/websocket.js
```

If I run this command in direct command line, it works fine.

But I want it automatically start when server PC turn on or restart.

So what I have done (according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/13388741/2193439 ) is-

Run `crontab -e` and put this code in the console-

```
@reboot forever start /var/www/websocket/websocket.js
```

like this-

[image]

And to check my corn log, I have done this-

```
sudo grep --color -i cron /var/log/syslog
```

And found something like this-

[image]

But I am finding the server is not running by this-

```
forever list
```

and having - **No forever processes running**

[image]

But if I run this-

```
forever start /var/www/websocket/websocket.js
```

And then run this-

```
forever list
```

Then I am having this-

[image]

And I am confirming you that crontab is also running because if I change this-

```
@reboot forever start /var/www/websocket/websocket.js
```

To this-

```
@reboot cd /var/www/websocket/ && touch cron_try.txt
```

I am having the file each time PC restarts.

---

I have already tried this-

1. [Automatically start forever (node) on system restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385029/automatically-start-forever-node-on-system-restart)
2. [Automatically restart node server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19779820/automatically-restart-node-server)
3. http://www.hacksparrow.com/make-forever-reboot-proof-with-cron.html
4. https://github.com/foreverjs/forever/issues/58

---

And this-

[cronjob does not execute a script that works fine standalone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36885909/cronjob-does-not-execute-a-script-that-works-fine-standalone)

Is almost my problem. But I had set it during reboot and for Node forever.js.

So it does not solve my problem.

---

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cronjob does not execute a script that works fine standalone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36885909/cronjob-does-not-execute-a-script-that-works-fine-standalone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this by this way-

First, find the forever location by this-

```
which forever
```

And get this-

```
/usr/local/bin/forever
```

And then put this path in `crontab` like this-

```
@reboot /usr/local/bin/forever start /var/www/websocket/websocket.js
```

And we are done :)

Comment: why did not you make a service ?